# How to connect and get track on SoundCloud API on universal app by Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, soundcloud

On the [SoundCloud tutorial](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference) I want to convert it make Json.NET and get whole tracks. How can I so this?

```
$ curl https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: use `WebClient` or `WebHttpRequest` to grab the data and feed it into json.net to deserialize it into your own c# object model.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just avoid creating the REST stuffs yourself and go with a wrapper like https://github.com/Haythem/SoundCloud.NET

Comment: It is MVVM. I need normal.

Comment: Which souldCloud get whole songs from by geners and searching?. if have  can you share link?
At here I just see "track"